# C# Datetime to ODBC Datetime conversion error

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime, odbc

We are trying to use ODBC with SQL Server 2012 for our new application because MS is phasing out OleDb and we want to try to make it easy (easier?) to port to other databases.

The problem is, when I try to use ODBC data access classes I get the following error when trying to save a datetime:

> ERROR [22008] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Datetime field
>   overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in
>   the parameter binding.

okay, I get that sort of. C# has a higher level of precision than the ODBC parameter wants to use. I understand that the ODBC implementation doesn't like fractions of seconds, but what is the work around to preserve the datetime precision?

Thanks,

Dinsdale

EDIT: Okay here is the original parameter constructor:

```
String Name = "created";
DateTime DateTimeValue = DateTime.Now;
OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand();
cmd.CommandType = request.CommandType;
cmd.CommandText = request.Command;
OdbcParameter param;
param = new OdbcParameter(Name, OdbcType.DateTime);
param.Value = DateTimeValue;
cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
```

This code generates the following error:
ERROR [22008] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.

The fix is to use an extended constructor like so:

```
param = new OdbcParameter(Name, OdbcType.DateTime, 23, System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input, false, 0, 3, Name, DataRowVersion.Current, DateTimeValue);
```

Thanks again to Kumod!
Dinsdale

Comment: can you show an example of how you are using the calls where these errors are occurring?

Answer (score 2):

> Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.

It means that second precision is greater than `Scale` property of the `OdbcParameter` object.
For `DateTime` formats:

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm` - `Precision = 16, Scale = 0`

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss` - `Precision = 19, Scale = 0`

And here are those which need `Scale` property to be exceeded (it's `0` by default)

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.f` - `Precision = 21, Scale = 1`

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.ff` - `Precision = 22, Scale = 2`

`yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.fff` - `Precision = 23, Scale = 3`

each `f` is additional fractional second precision

```
OdbcParameter param = new OdbcParameter( "name", OdbcType.DateTime );
param.Value = DateTime.Now;
param.Precision = 23;
param.Scale = 3; // <-- you need to set this property
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to get around the issue I encountered. I meant to post earlier but didn't get a chance. I ended up using and SQLDataAdapter and that resolved everything. For some reason the ODBCDataAdapter doesn't like doing what I was trying to do. Anyhow, hopefully this helps someone else eventually

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error recently without any desire to handle DateTime values of precisions down to less than a second. So I fed my failing datetime value into the following method:

```
public static object SetSafeDBDate(System.DateTime dtIn)
    {
        if (dtIn == new DateTime(0))
            return System.DBNull.Value;
        else
            return new DateTime(dtIn.Year,dtIn.Month,dtIn.Day,dtIn.Hour,dtIn.Minute,dtIn.Second);
    }
```

This solved the problem for me.