# Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, database, vb.net

When trying to move data of one table from SQL Server 2019 to SQL Server 2012 using a stored procedure with the help of linked server, I' getting this error:

> The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SalesServer1" could not INSERT INTO table "[LinkedServer1].[SalesDepart].[dbo].[Employee_Salary]".
> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "SalesServer1" returned message "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Datetime field overflow. Fractional second precision exceeds the scale specified in the parameter binding.

The table `Employee` structure is the same on both servers.

```
[Employee_Salary]
(
    [SalaryID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Amount] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CreatedDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EmployeeID][int] [NOT NULL]
)
```

When executing the stored procedure from SQL Server 2019 on `SalesDepart` database, I'm getting the exception shown above.

Query in the stored procedure:

```
--Insert record into Employee_Salary
INSERT INTO SalesServer1.SalesDepart.dbo.Employee_Salary
    ([SalaryID], [Amount], [Description], [Status], [CreatedDate], [EmployeeID])
    SELECT  
        SalaryID, Amount, Description, Status, CreatedDate, EmployeeID 
    FROM 
        Employee_Salary
```

Getting error for `CreatedDate` column, the datatype is `datetime`.

Comment: Employee , [Employee_Salary] or Z_ZYNX_ORDERSET_VERSIONS ?

Comment: This seems similar to the problem described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20695937/c-sharp-datetime-to-odbc-datetime-conversion-error